# Get JSon child with PHP echo from an API

Tags: php, json

Okay so bascially I have this structure as JSon from an API:

```
{
    "tag": "8L9L9GL",
    "name": "Jo͛hͥn̽",
    "trophies": 5338,
    "rank": 291,
    "arena": {
        "name": "Master II",
        "arena": "League 5",
        "arenaID": 17,
        "trophyLimit": 5200
    },
    "clan": {
        "tag": "2U2GGQJ",
        "name": "Reddit Bravo",
        "role": "coLeader",
        "donations": 0,
        "donationsReceived": 0,
        "donationsDelta": 0,
        "badge": {
            "name": "A_Char_Rocket_02",
            "category": "03_Royale",
            "id": 16000167,
            "image": "https://cr-api.github.io/cr-api-assets/badges/A_Char_Rocket_02.png"
        }
    },
```

I'm trying to get the Clan -> Name but it isn't working with this code in PHP:

```
echo "<p style='font-size:75;'>".$json->clan['name']."</p>";
```

How could I make it work?

Comment: `json_decode($json)->clan->name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "tag": "8L9L9GL",
    "name": "Jo͛hͥn̽",
    "trophies": 5338,
    "rank": 291,
    "arena": {
        "name": "Master II",
        "arena": "League 5",
        "arenaID": 17,
        "trophyLimit": 5200
    },
    "clan": {
        "tag": "2U2GGQJ",
        "name": "Reddit Bravo",
        "role": "coLeader",
        "donations": 0,
        "donationsReceived": 0,
        "donationsDelta": 0,
        "badge": {
            "name": "A_Char_Rocket_02",
            "category": "03_Royale",
            "id": 16000167,
            "image": "https://cr-api.github.io/cr-api-assets/badges/A_Char_Rocket_02.png"
        }
    }
}';

$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->clan->name;
```

// Reddit Bravo

If you want to use `$json['clan']['name'];` then you have to set the assoc param like:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['clan']['name'];
```

// Reddit Bravo

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$json->clan->name
```

Comment: echo "<p style='font-size:75;'>".$json->clan->name."</p>"; not working...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular call to `json_decode()`, if you've used...

```
$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
```

then use

```
echo "<p style='font-size:75;'>".$json['clan']['name']."</p>";
```

Else if you've used...

```
$json = json_decode($jsonData);
```

then use

```
echo "<p style='font-size:75;'>".$json->clan->name."</p>";
```

If using the first call, then you create an associative array and so use array access method.  If you don't pass `true` as the second parameter, this creates the structure as objects and so use the second method of access.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to json_decode the same and use it.

Following is the piece of code

```
echo json_decode($json)->clan->name;
```

Stitch it into your HTML as

```
echo "<p style='font-size:75;'>".json_decode($json)->clan->name."</p>";
```

Tested this snippet. Should work for you too.